# how i get JSON as string from url (java)

Tags: java, json, url

I want to save this JSON in url { https://www.instagram.com/ihanan95/?__a=1 }
and save it as string by java
I try used all suggestions but when do it I get empty string.

Comment: Please check answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Spring's](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) `RestTemplate` to get the response as `String`, e.g.:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://www.instagram.com/ihanan95/?__a=1", String.class);
System.out.println(response);
```

If you are not allowed to use third party libaries then you can do the same with `URLConnection`, e.g.:

```
URLConnection connection = new URL("https://www.instagram.com/ihanan95/?__a=1").openConnection();
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());){
    String response = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read JSON file from remote website.

Example:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.instagram.com/ihanan95/?__a=1");
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(url.openStream());
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tokener);
JSONObject data = obj.getJSONObject("user");
String message = data.getString("message");
```

JSONTokener [Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51273_03/ToolsAndFrameworks.110/apidoc/assembler/com/endeca/serialization/json/JSONTokener.html)

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The constructor JSONTokener(InputStream) is undefined

Comment: Please read the document : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51273_03/ToolsAndFrameworks.110/apidoc/assembler/com/endeca/serialization/json/JSONTokener.html